# What can cause StaleDataException other than prematurely calling cursor.close()?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager, android-loader, staledataexception

I'm currently heavily modifying/rewriting an Android app and I have seen a very occasional crash along the following lines: a `CursorAdapter` method is called, it calls `AbstractWindowedCursor#checkPosition()`, and:

```
02-20 15:03:18.180 E/AndroidRuntime(17143): android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
02-20 15:03:18.180 E/AndroidRuntime(17143): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
02-20 15:03:18.180 E/AndroidRuntime(17143): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
02-20 15:03:18.180 E/AndroidRuntime(17143): at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:106)
02-20 15:03:18.180 E/AndroidRuntime(17143): at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:220)
```

The trouble is, we're not closing any `Cursor`s.  All our `Cursor`s come from `CursorLoader`s and in turn are produced by a `ContentProvider`.  We're passing the `Cursor` into each respective `CursorAdapter` from the `LoaderCallbacks`, we're registering the `Cursor` for notifications in the `ContentProvider`, we're *notifying* the `ContentResolver` from each `insert(...)`, `delete(...)` and `update(...)` ... in short I can't find any reason why a `Cursor` would close while in use.

So: what are the *other* causes of a `StaleDataException`?

Comment: It's been a while since you asked, but... was there a FilterQueryProvider involved, by any chance?

Comment: Hey Andrew! Were you able to figure out the solution ?

Comment: I don't think we ever definitively tracked this down. However, we did discover that using a `Cursor` from outside the adapter provoked this behaviour, even though (again) we never called `.close()` or any method that you'd think caused this. Since then, I've always implemented `ContentObserver` and `DataSetObserver` in a manner analogous to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java (skip to the end) if I ever had to use a Cursor both inside and outside an adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling Cursor.changeCursor(newCursor), that will automatically close the old cursor for you. This can cause android.database.StaleDataException if anything is still trying to access the cursor.

Answer (score -3):

if you called `Context.managedQuery()` in android 4.0 and above, you should not call `Cursor.close()`, if you do so, `StaleDataException` will be thrown, you can modify you code as follow:

```
if(VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {  
    cursor.close();  
}
```